# How to call function of one controller from another controller AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two controller name called like:

1. `AutoLoginCtrl`
2. `LoginCtrl`

my facebook logout function present in Login Controller, from AutoLogin controller how could I call logout function which is Login Controller.

I have tried like this by using **$rootscope** and **$on**

**LoginCtrl.js**

```js
ionApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, $rootScope, $q, $timeout, UserService, $ionicLoading, $ionicActionSheet) {
$scope.showLogOutMenu = function() {
    var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
      destructiveText: 'Logout',
      titleText: 'Are you sure you want to logout? This app is awsome so I recommend you to stay.',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      cancel: function() {},
      buttonClicked: function(index) {
        return true;
      },
      destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Logging out...'
        });

        // Facebook logout
        facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function() {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $state.go('login');
          },
          function(fail) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          });
      }
    });
  };

  $rootScope.$on("LogoutFunction", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

})
```

**AutoLoginCtrl**

```js
ionApp.controller('AutoLoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, $rootScope, $q, $timeout, UserService, $ionicLoading, $ionicActionSheet) {
  var checkPage = "home";
$scope.logout = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit("LogoutFunction", {});
  }
})
```

Comment: Move the code for the logout to a service

Comment: @D. Simon, can't we call from controller?, because Idon't want to use service here.

Comment: Then what about using the same controller for both views?

Answer (score 0):

You decided to use `$emit` a.e. child controller notifies parent controller. Is it true? `AutoLoginCtrl` is a child of `LoginCtrl` or maybe you need to use `$broadcast` instead?

The second problem might be: 
For some reason `LoginCtrl` still didn't load and no one listens on `LogoutFunction` event.

---

Please check these cases

Comment: Sir am new to this, if we don't have parent child relationship between controller, how can I call function of another controller?

Comment: @Chandrashekhar both controller should be alive to make it work.  Take a look on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/714/    . Try to change `$emit`  to `$broadcast` or use service as  D. Simon mentioned

Answer (score 0):

you can make a Public Class (Provider Maybe) and make a function in it that call a function  'Logout()' from 'LoginController'
and call this provider function in Your 'AutoLogin' Controller

Answer (score 0):

You can have the logout function in a factory and call it from both the controllers, like this.

Factory basic demo: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mes1hszo/)

**Code:**

```
ionApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $rootScope, $q, $timeout, UserService, SharedService) {
$scope.showLogOutMenu = function() {
    SharedService.logout();
  };

}).factory('SharedService', function ($ionicActionSheet, $ionicLoading, $state) {
  return {
    logout: function () {
        var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
        destructiveText: 'Logout',
        titleText: 'Are you sure you want to logout? This app is awsome so I recommend you to stay.',
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        cancel: function() {},
        buttonClicked: function(index) {
          return true;
        },
        destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
          $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Logging out...'
          });

          // Facebook logout
          facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function() {
              $ionicLoading.hide();
              $state.go('login');
            },
            function(fail) {
              $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}).controller('AutoLoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $rootScope, $q, $timeout, UserService, SharedService) {
  var checkPage = "home";
$scope.logout = function() {
     SharedService.logout();
  }
});
```